Disable defaultProps warning from node modules
Is there a way to disable the default props warnings that are coming from my node modules?
"Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead."
There will not be any fixed version without default props for these libraries available any time soon, so I just would like to disable the warnings just for node modules.
The project is built using create react app and not ejected.

I would suggest to just downgrade to React 18.2.0 (the warnings have been introduced with version 18.3.0) if using maintained libraries is not a requirement for you.

@Arkellys I would like to maintain our code and keep it updated. But some of the node modules we are using, we do not have control over them and there is no replacement for that soon. So would like to keep our warnings clean.

@Arkellys I used react 18  but still got this error

@famfamfam Please read my comment carefully, the latest version of 18 has the warnings.
